# how to find columns in a pandas dataframe from an other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframe. The 1st one is like that:

```
df1

    ID_Societe  Pays
0   1829        FR
1   1321        FR
2   6536        CH
3   6426        CH
4   558         FR
....
```

and the second one:

```
df2

             558          1829          1321            1543        3470      etc...
Date                    
2015    497910000.0 1.920000e+09    6.100000e+08    140490000.0 2.340000e+09
2016    466420000.0 2.950000e+09    5.500000e+08    221150000.0 2.560000e+09
2017    465320000.0 1.980000e+09    9.080000e+09    310970000.0 3.640000e+09
2018    400450000.0 2.200000e+09    4.400000e+09    221520000.0 4.150000e+09
2019    368320000.0 3.000000e+09    6.400000e+08    135890000.0 6.180000e+09
2020    336130000.0 9.200000e+08    1.500000e+08    89940000.0  7.190000e+09
2021    427490000.0 1.450000e+09    1.400000e+08    91490000.0  1.029000e+10
2022    473240000.0 1.510000e+09    7.000000e+07    94170000.0  9.280000e+09
```

I would like to have a new dataframe which is a subset of df2 ie I did:

```
df2.loc[:, df1.query("Pays=='FR'")['ID_Societe'].squeeze()]
```

but because that all the df1.query("Pays=='FR'")['ID_Societe'].squeeze() seems to not exist in df2 I get an error message:

```
KeyError: '[1850, 1853, 2174, 1900, 1868, 2223, 1905, 5371, 1848, 7058, 1981, 3795, 1908, 1847, 1966, 1909, 1910, 6962, 1911, 3817, 1916, 1499, 3511, 1924, 2080, 1995, 1886, 1896, 2225, 1484, 2002, 3312, 3873, 1929, 1862, 1930, 3546, 5156, 1894, 1925, 6413, 6930, 1251, 1764, 2089, 5179, 2176, 3366, 6949, 1846, 1888, 1940, 1852, 1941, 1944, 3386, 6652, 5286, 2045, 1949, 1860, 5117, 1876, 1841, 1897, 1880, 1892, 6338, 1955, 1872, 2151, 1877, 1958, 1790, 1961, 2060, 8121, 1855, 1878, 1873, 2214, 3635, 1964, 1737, 4233, 1882, 1967, 1863, 1969, 1874, 7071, 6152, 2076, 6798, 3459, 4306, 6250] not in index'
```

How to skip these columns ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Index [`intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
df2[df2.columns.intersection(df1.query("Pays=='FR'")['ID_Societe'])]
```

Output:

```
                558         1829            1321
Date                    
2015    497910000.0 1.920000e+09    6.100000e+08
2016    466420000.0 2.950000e+09    5.500000e+08
2017    465320000.0 1.980000e+09    9.080000e+09
2018    400450000.0 2.200000e+09    4.400000e+09
2019    368320000.0 3.000000e+09    6.400000e+08
2020    336130000.0 9.200000e+08    1.500000e+08
2021    427490000.0 1.450000e+09    1.400000e+08
2022    473240000.0 1.510000e+09    7.000000e+07
```